# Calculating the percentage cover of multiple polygons

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am creating a habitat map for a woodland dependent species. I have multiple woodland polygons. Across the landscape the density of woodland varies widely and I would like to show that difference. I think the best way to show this would be with a raster grid, with cell colour relating to the percentage cover of woodland within that cell.

How do I convert polygons into a raster grid showing percentage cover?

[image: The current woodland polygons I have, in the grid cells I want]

Comment: What size of a grid are thinking of having?

Comment: 1km2 grid squares would be useful.

Comment: do you have grass gis installed or available to use the grass plugin or is it configured as a provider in processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create the sum (or percent) of woodland area from a polygon layer, I would convert the polygons to a fine resolution - say 1 meter - raster, then use the GRASS raster module `r.resamp.stats` to get a coarse resolution raster with 1 km. pixels. Use the "sum" method to get the total number of woodland pixels from the fine resolution grid into the coarse resolution.

The GRASS functions:

```
# Import woodland polygons into GRASS and convert to raster
# Assumes the woodlands shapefile in projected in some meters based CRS
v.in.ogr input=woodlands.shp output=woodlands 
g.region -p vect=woodlands res=1
v.to.rast woodlands output=woodlands_rast type=area
# Now get the coarse resolution raster with 
g.region -p res=1000
r.resamp.stats woodlands_rast output=woodlands_coarse method=sum
# Get percent by dividing by total area of each pixel and multiply by 100
r.mapcalc "woodland_pcent = (woodlands_coarse / 1000000)*100"
```

Note that there are some purpose built software for habitat analysis. For example you might want to check the [LecoS plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LecoS/)

Comment: Many thanks Micha, this is awesome. I've not used GRASS before so took me awhile to work out (resolution on a different tab, etc), but got there and the results are fantastic. Many thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the warm reply. Once you get your feet wet in GRASS (pun intended...) you'll never look back.